# Dark-corner with `typedef` in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, typedef

I recently found [Dark corners of C/C++: The typedef keyword doesn’t need to be the first word on the line](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130424-00/?p=4563) and was surprised knowing that all **looking-weird** `typedef`s below are all valid in both C and C++:

```
int typedef a;
short unsigned typedef b;
```

The above `typedef`s are equivalent to:

```
typedef int a;
typedef short unsigned b;
```

And, the following things are invalid in C++ but valid in C:

```
typedef enum { c };
typedef;
typedef int;
typedef int short;
```

Which are reasons behind that language designers have left this dark corner alive in C and C++?

Comment: Not breaking existing code?

Comment: From the article you linked: *"They are just alternate manifestations of the quirk in the grammar"*. So I don't think there's much of a reason behind them. The article also notes that some of those "loopholes" have been closed in C89.

Comment: I'm not sure why the first construct looks weird to you. Keywords can be placed differently in many other situations as well, for example `const int ` and `int const`,  `inline void foo(void);` and `void inline foo(void);`. Not sure about `typedef;`  though, it seems just useless, like `void;`.

Comment: Yeah, `struct {int a, b;} typedef num;` is also valid.

Comment: From memory, this "dark corner" is invalid in modern C and C++.   However, a number of compilers still permit it, probably for reasons of "backward compatibility" - and they can probably be configured (e.g. warning options) to give a warning about it.

Comment: I discussed this w/ Richard Smith the other day, it [inspired a tweet](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/1038137899911278592) and now I am struggling to remember if we discussed the rationale for this or not but most likely this is to keep the grammar simple.

Comment: I'll vote close, but will offer a comment first: While it's easy to find weird-looking corners, it's harder to find damaging effects of this weirdness, and *much* harder to find a clean and simple rule that allows what's useful and avoids damage.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour *"keeps the grammar simple"* - very funny...

Comment: As we could see in [ShafikYaghmour's quick survey](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/1038137899911278592): 55% out of 147 votes were supposed the weird-looking `typedef` ill-formed. It seems not worth having it just for... `keeping the grammar simple`

Comment: `typedef;` is not strictly conforming C. C 2018 6.7 2 says “A declaration other than a static_assert declaration shall declare at least a declarator (other than the parameters of a function or the members of a structure or union), a tag, or the members of an enumeration,” and that goes back to at least C 1999.

Comment: "Which are reasons behind that language designers have left this dark corner alive in C and C++?" They haven't. This has been marked an obsolete feature for 20 years. 6.11.5 "The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature." As for why they allowed `int typedef long const hello;` in the first place... who knows. Maybe the committee liked to smoke unmentionable substances during meetings? You are making the wrong assumption when you think there was some sort of sound rationale behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the main thing is to keep compatibility with old programs and libraries. There are a lot of them.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it is the same rule as for `cv` modifiers = a modifier applies:

- to the *first thing on its left*
- or if empty, on *the thing on its right*

Like `cv` modifiers (alias `const` `volatile` and `mutable`), I guess `typedef`follows the same rule.

> const applies to the thing left of it. If there is nothing on the left then it applies to the thing right of it.